# Is HBO's "Street 2" font family publicly available or is it a branded font?

Tags: typography, web-fonts

I have seen that the global HBO website uses a font called "Street 2". I've been looking for references to that font, but so far I have not found anything.

Is it a font available to the public or is it a font designed for HBO?

[image]

Comment: I would put the second font as it's own question.

Comment: A google search turns up a font at dafont.com -- perhaps posting an image or two would be beneficial.

Comment: Hi gabeweb, as WELZ said, if you want to ask about multiple fonts please ask another question

Comment: Hi WELZ, Cai, I just asked for the "Street 2" font from HBO and I mentioned "Netflix Sans" as a reference. Anyway, excuse me for my English if my question was misunderstood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any web font that is used to render live type on a web page is by definition accessible and downloadable (it has to be for your browser to be able to use it), so you can simply download the font and check for yourself...

The license info in the font's meta data reads:

> This font software is strictly limited to use by employees of Home Box Office, Inc., its domestic and global subsidiaries, and partners thereof. Distribution of this font software is strictly limited to client and service software, granted solely at the discretion of Home Box Office, Inc.
>
> [image]

So it looks like this is a custom font, not licensed for public use.

Answer (score 2):

The full name for the family is "HBO Street Sans" (Carvalho Bernau, 2016). It was not put to use publicly until late 2018.

It is not freely available, and is a custom font family commissioned by HBO Digital Products.

It replaces Gotham, which was used up until that point.

Street 2, by the way, is the default or "middle grade" of this font. Street 1 and Street 3 also exist.

The idea being that, depending on how fonts were rendered on a specific platform or device, the design team could switch the entire font stack to a very, very slightly heavier or lighter variant of the font, without requiring developers to make any time-consuming changes to the code of the product itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a custom family by Erik von Blokland (http://letterror.com/) and Carvalho Bernau (http://carvalho-bernau.com/info/). Atlas Grotesk (https://commercialtype.com/catalog/atlas) seems to be similar on first inspection, with one of the noticeable differences being the double-story 'g' in HBO Street 2. I'm curious if the "2" is a version number or variant (possibly width).

Comment: Yeah, and this is a common thing when you see a custom font you like that's proprietary: often seek out retail fonts by the same designer. Commonly they'll have designed one in a mood a big company liked so the big company requested a custom version they held rights to. Swiss Typefaces have created several custom fonts that look a bit like their popular Euclid family, for instance.